# Compare data table with same column in different table vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I want to create evaluation program to compare two tables (entry and validation) whether they have same data or not. The number of column two tables are same. For Example there are T_A_Entry, T_A_Val, T_B_Entry, T_B_Val, T_C_Entry, T_C_Val, etc.

I have populated all tables in database with combobox. combobox1 to select entry table, combobox2 to select validation table, combobox3 to select column (but this is optional). I can't figure out how to make comparison in each column.

[See image of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhSbp.jpg)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    svr = TextBox1.Text

    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

    If Button1.Text = " Connected " Then
        Button1.Text = "Connect"
        cn.Close()

        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call conDB()
    Try
        cn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Button1.Text = "Connected"

        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' ORDER BY 'TABLE_NAME' ASC"
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
            ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
            While dr.Read()
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr("TABLE_NAME"))
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(dr("TABLE_NAME"))
            End While
        End If
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Fail to Connect")
        Button1.Text = "Connect"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim xsql As String
    ' mencari nama kolom tabel
    xsql = " SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

    Call conDB()
    cn.Open()
    comm.CommandText = xsql
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        ComboBox3.Items.Clear()
        While dr.Read()
            ComboBox3.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Call FillGrid(ComboBox1.Text, ComboBox2.Text, ComboBox3.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub FillGrid(ByVal tabelEntry As String, ByVal tabelValidasi As String, ByVal variabel As String)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    'helpp....

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the order of the data matter?

Comment: actually it isn't important the order of data.